# Firing an electron towards a proton

Tags: electrostatics, electrons

Suppose I have an electron and a proton. If i fired the electron towards the proton, due to the attraction between them the path of the electron will change. How should I shoot the electron so that it starts to revolve the proton? (I think it is determined by the velocity that the electron was fired with)

Comment: ... and form a Hydrogen atom.

Comment: If the electron is at 'infinity' and you provide it additional energy when 'shooting' it, the electron cannot make a bound state in a two body system - it has too much energy and no way to shed it.

Comment: Re, "...so it starts to revolve [around?] the proton..." The idea of electrons in an atom "revolving" around the atom's nucleus like planets orbiting a star was abandoned by physicists around one hundred years ago.  In modern theory, the "location" of an electron is defined by its _[quantum state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state)_, and each possible quantum state of an electron in an atom is associated with a different three-dimensional standing wave pattern centered on the nucleus.